# Android image download

Tags: java, android, image, url, download

Hi i need to download image from url and then save that image to my android device but i am facing problems in getting image from url. Here is my code. Kindly help. I have attached my data class as well as my main activity class.

```
package muneeb.muneeba;

import android.graphics.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Picture 
{
   public String url;
   public String description;
   public String category;

   public Picture(String url,String desc,String category){
  this.url = url;
  this.description = desc;
  this.category = category;
   }

   public Bitmap getImage(){

  Bitmap image = null;

  try {
     InputStream in = new URL(url).openStream();
     image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return image;
   }
}

package muneeb.muneeba;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import android.util.Xml;

public class WebPics extends Activity
{
ArrayList<Picture> pictures;
int position = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    load();
    show();
}

private void load(){

   String line = "";
   TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

   try{

      URL url = new URL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47451150/pictures.xml");
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
      connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
      connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
      connection.setDoInput(true);

      connection.connect();

      StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( connection.getInputStream() ) );


      while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ){
         content.append(line);
      }

      line = content.toString();
      parse(line);
   } catch(Exception ex) {
      line = ex.getMessage();
      ex.printStackTrace();
   }

}

private void parse(String xml){

   String category = "";
   pictures = new ArrayList<Picture>();

   try{
      XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
      parser.setInput(new StringReader(xml));

      int event = parser.getEventType();
      while(event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){

         if(event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG &&
             parser.getName().equals("category") ) {

            category = parser.getAttributeValue(null,"name");
         }

         if(event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG &&
             parser.getName().equals("im") ){

             String url = parser.getAttributeValue(null,"url");
             String description = parser.getAttributeValue(null,"description");
             pictures.add(new Picture(url,description,category));
         }

         event = parser.next();
      }
   } catch(Exception ex){ }
}

private void show(){
   if(pictures != null){
      Picture picture = pictures.get(position);
      if (picture == null) return;

      ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
      image.setImageBitmap(picture.getImage());

      TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
      text.setText("Category:" + picture.category + "\n" + picture.description);
   }
}

public void buttonClick(View view){
   if(view.getId() == R.id.previous ){
      position--;
      if (position < 0) position = pictures.size() - 1;
   }

   if(view.getId() == R.id.next )
{
      position = (position + 1) % pictures.size();
   }

   show();
}

}
```

Comment: Image is not showing up.

Comment: Have you verified that you are getting the bitmap data?

Comment: yes, the size of my pictures array is zero so i am not getting any images

Comment: I recommend you to debug the parameter "url" and then copy and paste this value in a browser and verify that it is a correct image.

Comment: already done, image is opening on the browser

Comment: I think there is a problem in my parsing

Comment: That must be the case if your array size is 0.

Comment: So, I would debug "pictures" to discover why the elements are not added, because you said that your pictures array size was zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are not able to download your picture is because you are making network requests in UI thread which will not work.
Use `Asynctask` or any other mechanism to put all your network requests in non-UI thread and update your ImageView in UI thread. This way you'll be able to download your picture properly.
This [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask) may help you .

> Solution -

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... urls) {
           load();
            if(pictures == null) {
               return null;
            } else{
                Picture picture = pictures.get(position);
                if (picture == null)
                    return null;
                else
                    return picture.getImage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            if(bitmap == null){
                //Show error
            } else{
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
```

Add

```
new DownloadWebPageTask().execute();
```

wherever you wan to download pictures

Comment: Your "picture.getImage()" method also makes a network request. That should also be in a non-UI thread.

Comment: Add if(pictures != null){
      Picture picture = pictures.get(position);
      if (picture == null) return;
return picture.getImage();
      
   } in your doInBackground after you parse the output. And then set the returned bitmap to your imageView in onPostExecute()

Comment: still not working. can you please send me a running code?

Comment: You just created AsyncTask. You need to start that first using - new DownloadWebPageTask().execute();

Comment: I have tried everything but its not working. Please update my code and send me a working working one. I 'd be thankful.

Comment: Just add my AsyncTask and change @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  new DownloadWebPageTask().execute();
}

Comment: Still not working, I have replaced my async class with yours but no luck. also instantiated async class in activity on create() method

Comment: Please note that Toast in my load() function is also not appearing that means it is not executing my load() function.

Comment: ust add my AsyncTask and change @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.main); new DownloadWebPageTask().execute(); }  If this is not working , paste the code with the changes what I told you to do. Then only I can help you.

Comment: I did the changes.

Comment: Add  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> outside your <application> tag in Manifest file.

Comment: Its running now. Can you please tell me what i should do if i want to download any of these images to my computer using on click event of image?

Comment: Also, you cannot programmatically save the images from your phone to the computer. If you want to manually do it , use Android Device Monitor(ADM)

Comment: Sorry, I want to save my image to my android device gallery. Please help me with this one too

Comment: i am facing one last issue. image of 1st picture object is displayed but for the rest objects only description is being showed and image is not being displayed. Please help me fix this.

Comment: Please raise a different question for this with the relevant code.

Comment: i am facing one last issue. image of 1st picture object is displayed but for the rest objects only description is being showed and image is not being displayed. Please help me fix this.

Comment: Please raise a different question for this with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

```
package muneeb.muneeba;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import android.util.Xml;

public class WebPics extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Picture> pictures;
    int position = 0;
    Context c;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        c = this;
        new DownloadWebPageTask().execute();
    }

    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            load();
            if(pictures == null) {
                return null;
            } else{
                Picture picture = pictures.get(position);
                if (picture == null)
                    return null;
                else
                    return picture.getImage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            if(bitmap == null){
                //Show error
            } else{
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
        private void load() {

            String line = "";
            TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

            try {
                Toast.makeText(c, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                URL url = new URL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47451150/pictures.xml");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setDoInput(true);

                connection.connect();

                StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));


                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(line);
                }

                line = content.toString();
                parse(line);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                line = ex.getMessage();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        private void parse(String xml) {

            String category = "";
            pictures = new ArrayList<Picture>();

            try {
                XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
                parser.setInput(new StringReader(xml));

                int event = parser.getEventType();
                while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                    if (event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG &&
                            parser.getName().equals("category")) {

                        category = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                    }

                    if (event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG &&
                            parser.getName().equals("im")) {

                        String url = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "url");
                        Toast.makeText(c, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        String description = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "description");
                        pictures.add(new Picture(url, description, category));
                    }

                    event = parser.next();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

        public void buttonClick(View view) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.previous) {
                position--;
                if (position < 0) position = pictures.size() - 1;
            }

            if (view.getId() == R.id.next) {
                position = (position + 1) % pictures.size();
            }
            show();
        }
    public void show() {
        if (pictures != null) {
            Picture picture = pictures.get(position);
            if (picture == null) return;

            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageBitmap(picture.getImage());

            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Category:" + picture.category + "\n" + picture.description);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Remove  TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text); and Toast from load()

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="muneeb.muneeba" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <activity android:name=".WebPics"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```